# I am trying to store the document term matrix in a dictionary in python using Zip, but its throwing following error:-

Tags: python, pandas, countvectorizer

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(tokenizer = lambda x: x.split())
tag_dtm = vectorizer.fit_transform(tag_data['Tags'])

#'get_feature_name()' gives us the vocabulary.
tags = vectorizer.get_feature_names()

freqs = tag_dtm.sum(axis=0).A1
result = dict(zip(tags, freqs))
```

When i run this code, i am getting the following error:

```
  1 freqs = tag_dtm.sum(axis=0).A1
----> 2 result = dict(zip(tags, freqs))
TypeError: 'ZipFile' object is not callable
```

I am using google colab for this. The code snippet is working fine in jupyter notebook but not in colab.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As a new user you really should read [ask]. And wonder how someone that does not know what happened before the line `result = dict(zip(tags, freqs))` could help you: what are `tags`, and `freqs`, **I** cannot guess. Unless you provide a reproducible [mcve], this question cannot be answered except with wild guesses, and unfortunately, my crytal ball is currently out of use.

Comment: Please provide more code. One guess though, did you use zip as a variable name earlier in your code? If you did, you won't them be able to use the built in zip function.

Comment: Somwhere in your code you have *shadowed* the built-in `zip` function by assigning a `ZipFile` object to the name `zip`.

Comment: @JohnSloper , i haven't used zip as variable anywhere. But i used zip to extract my csv file from zipped folder before this code line.

Comment: @wwii yes i have used `ZipFile` before to extract my csv file. i am new to python. please help!

Comment: `from zipfile import ZipFile
file_name = "Train.zip"

with ZipFile(file_name, 'r') as zip:
  zip.extractall()
  print("Done")`

Comment: It is always best to avoid variable names that match a build in function. E.g. change it to: `from zipfile import ZipFile file_name = "Train.zip" with ZipFile(file_name, 'r') as zip_file: zip_file.extractall() print("Done")`

Comment: `with ZipFile(file_name, 'r') as zip:...` - use something other than `zip` as the name.  Did you write the code?

Comment: Thank you ! Nope, i copied it from colab docs..